# Load a Pop Up Window Using a URL Link

Tags: javascript, html, popup

I'm looking for a way to open a window as a popup, by just using a URL. For the landing page creator all I have access to is to the past the URL, so I can't put in any scripts at all.

As an example this is what I think is possible but don't know to do it.

URL goes to:

http://www.example.com/popup-redirect.html
This page could just call a popup and execute

Real Popup Windown 400X500
http://www.example.com/real-popup.html

The popup-redirect.html can just load the real-popup.html without actually loading the page or opening and closing it quickly.

Would this be possible?

popup-redirect.html can be php as well.

Thanks!

Comment: Please don't use unnecessary tags.

Comment: Can you show me where this question was asked Praveen? I've seen variations with it, but they all involved being able to use more than just a URL in the link.

Can you show me or allow me to ask this question. Thank you!

Comment: What all tags did you use Terry? Why did you use [tag:java] and [tag:php]? Answer it. It doesn't matter, I can easily direct you to the right answer.

Comment: Lemme know if I made a mistake.

Comment: I have reopened the question. Expect a lot of questions. Your question is not at all clear.

Comment: Because the popup-redirect.html page can be php. I would assume HTML alone will not do the trick as it won't load anything special and Java script can be used as HTML alone will not do the trick, I'm pretty sure. I put Javascript because even to open an onclick javascript you would need it.

Comment: Hi Praveen, if you can direct me to the right answer I'd appreciate it just the same. I spent a day looking at different forums including stackoverflow before asking.

Comment: Use `target="_blank"` in the `<a>` tag, that will open the link in a new window.

Comment: Hi Barmar, thanks for your response. All I have access to is the URL, I'm using a landing page creator, they don't allow any additional code.

this is all I'm allowed to have: http://www.example.com/page-xxx.html or http://www.example.com/page-xxx.php

Answer (score 0):

Put the following in `popup-redirect.html`:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=javascript:window.open('http://www.example.com/real-popup.html');">
```

or:

```
<script type="text/javascript">window.open('http://www.example.com/real-popup.html');</script>
```

However, it's possible that popup blockers may block these.

Comment: Hi Barmar, thanks for your response. All I have access to is the URL, I can't even add the target="_blank"  I'm using a landing page creator, they don't allow any additional code. this is all I'm allowed to have: example.com/page-xxx.html or example.com/page-xxx.php. The landing page creator allows me to open the URL in a new page with a checkbox, but it's not allow me to add target="_blank" code. The only way I can think of doing this is open a page let that page execute the popup and close the other page. Or have the new page just redirect to the popup.

Comment: I did see your edit and just tried it. Thanks!
You're right Barmar, it gets blocked, is there a way to open it in a window with specific dimensions?

Comment: You can use the optional arguments to `window.open()` to specify the dimensions and other attributes. Read the documentation for the details.

Comment: After trying this, I don't think the popup is the right solution. I'm just wondering is a solution where it would call a PHP, the PHP file would just open the window as a popup on the page the link is from? Thank you regardless.

Comment: Not sure I understand you. You said a popup is not the right solution, then you asked how to open it as a popup. Do you mean an HTML dialogue within the same page? That definitely requires Javascript on the original page.